# How can I overload functions with pattern matching in Swift?

Tags: swift, pattern-matching, overloading, func

In other high level languages you can use pattern matching for function overloading, such as in Mathematica. For example, you can write elegant code without if statements, here's an example of what I mean:

sing Fibonacci:

```
fib[0|1] := 1
fib[n_Integer?Positive] := fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]
fib[n__] := fib /@ {n}
fib[n_] := "undefined"
```

Here's:

```
In[]:= fib[10]
Out[]= 89

In[]:= {fib[-2], fib["2"]}    
Out[]= {"undefined", "undefined"}

In[]:= fib[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Out[]= {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21}
```

Does swift have functionality of this sort for pattern based arguments or something like it?

Comment: Please remember to tag your questions with the language.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! Sorry, I'm a newbie, should I post this somewhere else?

Comment: No, this is fine. You just needed to put `swift` in the tag list. I already fixed it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Swift doesn't have pattern-matching in its overloads, only type & protocol matching. The best you can do is:

```
func fib(n: Int) -> Int {
    switch n {
    case 0, 1: return 1
    default: return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    }
}

func fib(s: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return s.map { fib($0) }
}


fib(10)         // 89
fib([3, 4, 5])  // [3, 5, 8]
```

I'll leave handling negative input as an exercise for the reader. :)

---

A fully generic version that can handle any integer input would use generic functions, like this:

```
func fib<T: IntegerType>(n: T) -> T {
    switch n {
    case 0, 1: return 1
    default: return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    }
}

func fib<S: SequenceType, T : IntegerType where T == S.Generator.Element>(s: S) -> [T] {
    return map(s) { n in
        return fib(n)
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor note: The first two cases could be combined to `case 0, 1: return 1`, which resembles the given Mathematica code a bit more.

Comment: (But I doubt that the generic version is useful here. As an example, `fib(Int8(20))` would crash due to overflow)

Comment: @MartinR Great points - I started the generic first, and used `IntegerArithmeticType`, which isn't literal convertible, but then never cleaned up. Fixed now.

Comment: And yeah, perhaps it should return IntMax -- maybe that's why they added that alias?